# E-IMZO: API-key для домена недействителен

Tags: javascript

У меня на компьютере установлена программа e-imzo,
Файл ключа  находится в c:\DSKEYS\DS224582210101.pfx
e-imzo открывается в   https://127.0.0.1:64443/
Накидал простенькую html,  что бы понять хоть как работает.

Объявляю в  html/js  переменную
если у меня программа будет работать на локальном компьютере, какой еще домен и API-KEY добавлять надо, откуда их брать??

```
  var API_KEYS = [
  'localhost', '96D0C1491615C82B9A54D9989779DF825B690748224C2B04F500F370D51827CE2644D8D4A82C18184D73AB8530BB8ED537269603F61DB0D03D2104ABF789970B',
  '127.0.0.1', 'A7BCFA5D490B351BE0754130DF03A068F855DB4333D43921125B9CF2670EF6A40370C646B90401955E1F7BC9CDBF59CE0B2C5467D820BE189C845D0B79CFC96F'
  // добавьте свой Домен и API-KEY сюда
];
```

затем вызываю, и тут проходит все по success

```
 CAPIWS.apikey(API_KEYS, function (event, data) {
    if (data.success) {
window.alert("Успешно - можно вызывать функции E-IMZO"); 
    } else {
        // Ошибка - возможно API-KEY недействительный
        window.alert(data.reason);
    }
}, 
function(error){
  // Ошибка WebSocket соединения
  window.alert(error);
});
```

потом пытаюсь получить id  ключа и у меня выскакивает ошибка   API-key для домена недействителен?

```
CAPIWS.callFunction({
    plugin    :"pfx",
    name      :"load_key",
    arguments :[
      //Диск
      "C:",
      //Путь (должна быть пустой или 'DSKEYS')
      "DSKEYS",
      //Имя файла без расширения
      " DS224582210101 ",
      //Алиас ключа
      " DS224582210101 "
    ]
  },
  function(event, data){
    
console.log(data); 
window.alert(Object.values(data)[0]);
```

Comment: в общем я разобрался.  ДИСК должен быть C:\\,  ПУТЬ так и есть ИМЯ ФАЙЛА так и есть, а вот ALIAS надо брать полное описания из ключа, это доп функция  //запрос всех сертификатов
CAPIWS.callFunction({    plugin    :"pfx",     name      :"list_all_certificates"}